# Removing background and keeping transparencies in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Is it possible to remove the black from an image like this in Photoshop so it is only white but respect the transparency? I am aware that a Screen blending mode would give this effect but I need to completely remove the background and import it in another program as a png with no background.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you need to save/export an image with only the white and transparency...

- `Select > Select All`
- `Edit > Copy`
- Fill the layer with white (trust me)
- Add a **Layer Mask** to the layer
- In the **Channels Panel** (`Window > Channels`), Turn **on** visibility and **highlight** the **mask channel**
- `Edit > Paste`
  <sub>(As seen in the animation below, if you fail to turn on visibility for the mask *channel* the "paste" will create a new layer.)</sub>
- Click the Layer thumbnail in the **Layers Panel**

[image]

Save and you should have white with transparency.
<sup>(Additional layer added in animation simply so things are visible.)</sup>

---

For internal editing in Photoshop ---
<sup>(I realize you mentioned this in the question. Simply being complete.)</sup>

Change the **Blending Mode** to `Screen` and only the white will show on layers below.

[image]